# How to detect what is responsible for high jitter?

Tags: networking, home-networking, streaming

I'm trying to stream between two computers connected via switch (Ethernet). However it looks like the high jitter is not allowing for smooth transfer (at least according to in-program test mode). How to detect which part (cables? cards?) is responsible for the problem?

I think I ruled out switch as I borrowed a higher end one and problem persisted.

Comment: Before looking to place the blame on hardware, make sure that no other traffic is flowing on the same link.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm reasonably certain that's not the case.

Comment: The problem turned out to be in CPU quantas of all things. Increasing quanta time improved performance.